# Make the elements of a matrix bold if it exceeds a specified value

Tags: r, matrix, graphics

I have never encountered someone marking the values of a large matrix or dataframe based on a pre-defined value. For my application, it would be very useful as I have a symmetric matrix of 20x20.

Reproducible example:

`sample.data <- matrix(data = c(1:30), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)`

Then bold for example all the values that exceed the value of 5. By using `which(sample.data > 5)`, I understand I can get the positions of the ones that exceed 5. I am after also marking them, for example in bold (as that would be really clear) in the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output your 20x20 matrix to Excel. Then, in Excel, highlight your matrix and click "conditional formatting".

I know it's heresy to make an Excel suggestion in this forum, but making your data bold is one of those (rare) things that Excel - *ahem* - excels at :)

Comment: Realised I did not accept this as the best answer, but imo you're right. This worked best for my situation

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `pander` package to generate a table formatted for markdown.

```
sample.data <- matrix(data = c(1:30), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
sample.data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

To bold greater than 12, do:

```
library(pander)
emphasize.strong.cells(which(sample.data > 12, arr.ind = TRUE))
pandoc.table(sample.data)

--- ---- -------- -------- --------
 1   6      11     **16**   **21** 

 2   7      12     **17**   **22** 

 3   8    **13**   **18**   **23** 

 4   9    **14**   **19**   **24** 

 5   10   **15**   **20**   **25** 
--- ---- -------- -------- --------
```

Copied as text here:

---

1   6      11     **16**   **21**

2   7      12     **17**   **22**

3   8    **13**   **18**   **23**

4   9    **14**   **19**   **24**

5   10   **15**   **20**   **25**

---

See [pander documentation](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#pander-an-r-pandoc-writer) or the [author's blog](http://blog.rapporter.net/2013/04/hihglight-cells-in-markdown-tables.html)

Answer (score 1):

Make a `gtable`

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(magrittr)

sample.data <- matrix(data = c(1:30), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

face <- cut(sample.data, c(0, 8, 25), 
  labels=c("plain", "bold")) %>% as.character

fcol <- cut(sample.data, c(0, 12, 22, 25), 
  labels=c("black", "darkred", "red")) %>% as.character

t1 <- ttheme_default(base_size=18, core=list(
        fg_params=list(fontface=face, col=fcol)
        ))

grid.table(sample.data, theme=t1)
```

[image]